# Ring automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: ring-theory

What are the all possible ring automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$?
According to me, it is completely determined by its value on $\sqrt{2}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, but what is your argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. It is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and as such any automorphism, $\phi$, of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is determined by its basis elements, in this case $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$. Since this is a ring homomorphism we have $1\mapsto 1$ and the automorphism is completely determined by the image of $\sqrt{2}$.

Furthermore, we must have $\phi(\mathbb{\sqrt{2}})^2=2$ since all elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ are invariant under $\phi$ due to the image of $1$. Denoting $x=\phi(\sqrt{2})$ we have $x^2-2=0$ and $x=\pm \sqrt{2}$. This gives the complete set of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, namely the two maps $\sqrt{2}\mapsto \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}\mapsto-\sqrt{2}$.